# Manipulating Javascript RegExp results as non-strings

Tags: javascript, regex

It's much easier to show the Javascript code than offer a complex explanation:

`var html = '<input tabindex="1" type="text">';

html.replace(/tabindex="([0-9]+)"/g, 'tabindex="' + ("$1" * i) + '"');`

In this code, "$1" will always be a string, meaning this RegExp will always result in 'tabindex="NaN"' ... Using parseInt doesn't work.

Is it possible to cast the response from the RegExp as an integer so I can perform maths on the replacement?

Comment: CMS and outis have given you your answer. Just out of curiosity, what are you attempting to do with this code?

Comment: I have a block of HTML being cloned within the DOM, and want to ensure the attributes are correctly updated once cloned. Simple stuff, and the above is a further simplification, as a better example.

Comment: As outis said, then, you should definitely consider `cloneNode` and not HTML string hacking. Then you can use simple assignments like `newelement.tabindex= oldelement.tabindex*i`, and you don't have to worry about exact HTML formats (eg. IE's `innerHTML` returning you `tabindex=2` without any quotes). The only gotcha is that in IE (oh, IE, again, how we love you), assigning the `name` attribute has some wrinkles.

Comment: This is a very specific case where a larger chunk of HTML, (lots of elements), is available as a string in the JS, rather than in the DOM. 

It's way quicker to use a simple search and replace or RegExp rather than to create the element and then trawl through the various child nodes and update them - I wrote the DOM manipulation first but clocked it about 10 x as slow within Firebug, hence looking to improve the speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement argument [can be a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
html.replace(/tabindex="([0-9]+)"/g, function (all, tabindex) {
        return 'tabindex="' + (tabindex * i) + '"'
    });
```

However, you should only be using regexps to manipulate HTML if you don't have a parser. If this code is to run in a browser, then you have a parser. If the node is coming from another document, use [`document.importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode). If the node is in the same document, use [`Node.cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode). Both support deep copying.